# My package.el is broken

Tags: package, package-repositories

About 2 weeks ago my package.el broken and I am not able to install/remove/update packages.

Flow: M-x package-list-packages, I mark package for installation or deletion (I or D appears next to package name), press 'r', in minibuffer Connection host: elpa/melpa/org appears and then the last repository in my package-archives hangs there, I or D dissapears from package name and nothing happens, package is not installed/removed.

Package-related stuff in my .emacs:

I tried basically anything, emacs -Q, google, ask in freenode #emacs, no help. Only similar thing I found was this 3 years old issue https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/issues/698 which kinda seems like whats happening to me, but no mouse movement helps.

Thanks for any help.

BTW: I can install packages with package-install without any problem and my package-archives is correct.

Comment: Are you on Linux? Does the error message contain anything related to SSL? I too have similar problems with Melpa because of certificate mismatch or something like that... Can you reproduce the exact error message? Also, look into `*Messages*` buffer in case you missed something.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would backup my .emacs and move it. Then re-open Emacs and try to install a package. If that succeeds, then I would methodically reinstate bits of my .emacs until I find the culprit.

[My config](https://github.com/yurrriq/dotfiles/tree/emacs) is (increasingly) organized into files separated by package/area of concern. That way, it's MUCH easier to isolate and resolve issues like yours. [Steve Purcell's .emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d) is a great resource for organizational style and tricks.

If a "clean" Emacs (without your current .emacs) is still unable to install a package, then I would reinstall Emacs entirely as clearly you've got bigger issues.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, as I said, it is the same with -Q and not even uninstalling emacs and removing .emacs.d does anything.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. When I mark packages for installation/deletion/upgrade, I press `x` for [`package-menu-execute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Menu.html).